# How to acknowledge a dialog to open another application in TestCafe

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I want to acknowledge a dialog which chrome prompts when it wants to open an application. So far I have tried the `t.setNativeDialogHandler(() => true).click(itemToOpenDialog)` but without any luck. Have anybody found a way to do this?
[Link to dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3i6w.png)

Running:

- testcafe `1.7.1`
- nodejs `8.12.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [setNativeDialogHandler](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/handling-native-dialogs.html) method is intended for the native alert/confirm/prompt, and beforeunload dialogs. It does not support the "open another application" dialog and cannot be used to interact with it.

Instead, you can verify the hyper-link's href attribute. It should contain the protocol that opens another application like "skype:...", "msteams:...", etc. If the hyper-link contains the necessary protocol, this will be sufficient for a test case.